# How to test microsoft graph api requests that query parameters to customize responses?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently working on a project where I call a microsoft graph api endpoint in a controller passing in to it a parameter and returning a customised response which is a filtered list of users that ends up being displayed on a table.

Does it make sense to test this or is it enough just to mock the controller action method in a unit test? What is the actual proper way to test graph api requests that have query parameters and then return customised responses, like for example filter, select etc..?

> This is the request being made to a graph api end point. This method gets called in the controller and returns a list of filtered users.

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUserByNameAsync(string param){

return await this.appClient.Users
    .Request(this.queryOptions)
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .Filter($"startswith(DisplayName,'{param}') or startswith(GivenName,'{param}') or 
    startswith(Surname,'{param}') or startswith(Mail,'{param}')").Select(@$"
    Id,
    DisplayName,
    GivenName,
    Surname,
    Mail,
    OtherMails,
    CompanyName");
}
```

> The controller where I call my method

```
public ActionResult GetFilteredUsers(param)
    {
        var filteredUsers = GetUserByNameAsync(param)
        return View(filteredUsers);
    }
```

> Mocking/ setting up GetUserByNameAsync() method that send a request with a parameter. I pass in this.Users which consists of 10 user objects.

```
private readonly Mock<IGraphAPI> repositoryMockGraphAPI;

this.repositoryMockGraphAPI.Setup(api => api. 
GetUserByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>. 
())).ReturnsAsync(this.Users);
```

> This is my test where I pass in one user so to test whether the 10 users I set up above will be filtered down to one only. However the
> this.b2CRepository.GetUsersByName(displayName); always returns all of the users i.e does not filter! It should return one matching users instead it returns all the users in this.users!

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetUsersByName(){
var displayName = "TestUser-" + 1;
var users = this.b2CRepository.GetUsersByName(displayName);
}
```

Comment: Did you met any issue or error? your code snippet indicating you are now using the graph SDK. did it work for you?

Comment: My question is about how one would test a method that sends a request to the graph api? In my case I am sending a request with a parameter that returns a filtered list of users! How would one go about testing a method like that i.e assert that for a given parameter the matching users a returned..